# Extracting rules in regression tree in Python

Tags: python, r, regression, decision-trees

I don't know if this question is a complicated question or not. I wanna train a regression tree in which in leaves, linear regression is applied to predict. Then, when the tree and linear regression models are trained, extract all rules and regression models.
Is there any package or library to do this?